# Как узнать сколько раз запускалось приложение

Tags: android

Мне нужно считать сколько раз запустили мое приложения

Comment: для начала нужно определиться с тем, что считать "запустили". Я работаю в приложении, пришло сообщение в телеграм, я перешел в телеграм, ответил, вернулся в приложение туда же, откуда ушел. Сколько раз я запустил - один или два? Второй вариант: я работаю в приложении, надоело, свернул, через полдня опять открыл. Оно за все время так и не выгрузилось из оперативки и открылось точно там же, где я его оставил. Сколько раз я запустил - один или два?

Answer (score 4):

Есть несколько "сравнительно точных способов подсчета" (аллюзия на фразу Остапа, который знал 400 сравнительно честных способов отъема денег).

Самый простой - это когда приложение испускает "крик младенца" каждый раз при запуске. Например, шлет запрос на какой то сервер. При этом вы можете добавить туда идентификатор экземпляра, тогда  у вас будет статистика и по кол-ву пользователей, и по частоте хзапуска приложения.

Второй по простоте - это использование централизованного логгера, чего то вроде loggly. Ну, или кто Вам больше понравится. Из анализа логов можно узнать не только, сколько раз запускалось приложение, но и какие ошибки возникали у пользователей.

Третий способ - косвенный. Самый неточный. По числу загрузок (их то Вам магазин показывает) и по кол-ву оставленных отзывов.

А так - можете уточнить вопрос, тогда ответ можно будет конкретизировать.

Comment: Самый простой он же самый сложный так как нужен еще Бэкенд и прочие радости для прослушки крика младенца

Comment: ну, такой бэкэнд придумать довольно просто. Можно запустить пустой Nginx и просто анализировать его логи. В то же время, нельзя не отметить, что самый простой способ - это, по сути, "велосипед", создание котрых в некотрых программистских религиях считается греховным. А вообще я посмотрел - в sdk, как правило, входят способы логгирования, в том числе, и в облако. Видимо, этот способ лучше и стандартнее